Where is the interface definition for ARM clang's aeabi_ldivmod and __divmoddi4 builtins?
I am trying to understand the compiled code for our ARM embedded system, using armclang compiler. Specifically, our code has a 64-bit signed division, which is translated to a call to the aeabi_ldivmod builtin. I was able to find its source code here, and it seems like it calls another builtin: __divmoddi4. Trying to look for the source code of this one, I come up with nothing. The closest thing I found is divmodsi4.S, but this is for 32-bit values.

Where can I find the source code to __divmoddi4? Specifically, I am looking for the function's interface definition (not the C prototype). I am interested in understanding what registers are passed in and out.

Where can I find the interface for the caller, aeabi_ldivmod?



https://github.com/microsoft/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/builtins/divmoddi4.c  Ultimately you will get here (which does something). https://github.com/microsoft/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/builtins/udivmodti4.c

@artlessnoise - first of all, thanks for the pointers. Apparently I did not look at the whole list of builtins in the code tree there. However, looks like this is not platform-specific section of the tree, and thus is the C implementation, which does not show the assembly-level interface.

The assembler may call the 'C' interface.  It is not required that assembler only calls other assembler code.  Are you sure that assembler variants exist?  You can look at a generated map file and it should list archive modules linked.  Also, you can look at the disassembler and see if it matches the routine.

You are right that it is possible, but at this level of functionality, you'd implement the operations in the most efficient way you could. After fiddling around I think that what I am looking for might be ARM's proprietary code, and I will not be able to find the sources (the compiler we use is armclang which is ARM's port of the public clang/llvm compiler). So it is possible that some parts are not found in places like github. Anyway, I was able to see the implementation using disassembly of the binary and use intelligent guesses on the registers passed and the implementation itself.

you'd implement the operations in the most efficient way.  In fact, modern compilers are really difficult to beat.  I think the assembler is just to coerce arguments or keep an ABI for the calls.  Hand code assembler is not necessarily better.  The optimal is to let the register allocator get involved.  Usually, these routines are not a 'default division', but present for a pedantic standard compliance.  The compile will attempt to inline divisions if possible, but these routines are called with no optimization and/or when the compiler can make no assumptions about operands.

So, I would argue that the compiler developers think it is better to optimize code generation than hand code assembler (which will not be optimal arch to arch, cpu to cpu) and instead concentrate on front/back end issues.  But I think clearly neither of us know; I would just advise you not to default to thinking "It must be in assembler".

I don't think we disagree.
